# OS independent programming of bitfields

Tags: c++, visual-studio, gcc, bit-fields

I have to program independent bits in a bitfield spanning multiple DWORDS. I am currently using a struct as follows

```
typedef struct _myStruct
{
    union 
    {
        struct 
        {
            DWORD   field1       : 16
            DWORD   field2       : 8
            DWORD   field3       : 8
        };
        DWORD   value0;
    };
    union 
    {
        struct 
        {
            DWORD   field4       : 32; 
        } 
        DWORD   value1;
    };
} myStruct;
```

I do this so that a programmer can access independent fields directly, and not remember the corresponding DWORD i.e. as `myStruct.field1` etc.
This works well in Visual Studio, however GCC complains when I used unnamed structs and unions. To correct that I tried naming the unions and structs as below:

```
    union _DW0
    {
        struct _BF
        {
            DWORD   field1       : 16
            DWORD   field2       : 8
            DWORD   field3       : 8
        } BF;
        DWORD   value0;
    } DW0;
```

But now the access is not programmer friendly.. i.e. someone who tries to program this have to remember which DWORD each field belongs to. For eg: `myStruct.DW0.field1`

Is there a way to get around this?

Comment: **TYPO:** myStruct.DW0.field1 in the last line to be read as myStruct.DW0.BF.field1

Comment: Your question seems to be more about support for anonymous struct support rather than bitfields. However, you should keep in mind that if you're expecting bitfields to be 'binary portable' (ie., that the layout of the bitfields match) across compilers and platforms, that can be a bit of a minefield.

Comment: Might be worth explaining why you can't use std::bitset or boost::dynamic_bitset

Comment: Other than 4 missing semicolons [this works fine in gcc 4.3.4 and newer](http://ideone.com/DBl22).

Comment: @Dave: *Works fine in gcc 4.3.4 and newer* and *OS independent* are completely different things.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas yes but the OP said it didn't.

Comment: @Jon I am programming the bits directly into hardware. So at this level, I assume that using STL would cause performance degradation. I haven't tested that though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bitfields are inherently non-portable. When you write `DWORD field1 : 16;` the standard does not determine whether `field1` should have the higher or lower 16 bits of the struct. On the other hand, if you use proper types and unions (which in your case suffice, since all your bitfields match a type in most platforms), that *can* be portable.

Using C++11 types (you can alternatively use a library that has the proper types for your platform):

```
union {
   struct {
      uint16_t  _1;
      uint8_t   _2;
      uint8_t   _3;
   } field;
   uint32_t value;
};
// ...
```

Comment: Why didn't you use an unnamed struct?

Comment: @Dave: That **is** an unnamed struct, and a variable with that name.

Comment: I am programming for one platform, so I don't care about portability across platforms, or endianness. However, I do care about portability across OS. I have typedef-ed DWORD to be unsigned 32 bit int in all OS. Also, my bitfields were only an example.. the bit fields may even be values other than 16, 8.. so I can't use uint16_t and uint8_t as described above.

Comment: @Deepak: this is not an issue of endianness, in the same platform and even OS two compilers could decide to represent bitfields differently. The specification of bitfields is very very lax. Stated in a different way: `union U { struct A { unsigned char a : 4; unsigned char b : 4; } a; char u}; A value; value.a.a = 15;` If you print `value.u` in hex it will be either `0x0F` or `0xF0`, and the standard places no requirement on which one it is. Bitfields are highly non-portable for this reason.

Answer (score 0):

Anonymous unions are generally okay, but structures need to have a name.  You may be able to use that to cut out one level of 'dot' from your syntax.

However, you're going to have to have slightly-messy syntax if you need to access the fields both individually (as bitfields) *and* as a whole (as DWORDS) through named structure members.  That sort of use case necessitates the union, which necessitates the inner struct, which causes the problem.  You can always hide all of the messy syntax behind getter/setter functions but if the structure is large, then that method will not be very maintainable.

Here is an alternative that you can consider:

```
typedef struct
{
    // DWORD 0
    DWORD   field1   : 16;
    DWORD   field2   : 8;
    DWORD   field3   : 8;
    // DWORD 1
    DWORD   field4   : 32; 
} bitfield_struct;
```

This only gives you bitfield-level access, but the syntax is cleaner.  You can still access the data on the DWORD level if needed, though:

```
bitfield_struct foo;
DWORD* bar = (DWORD*)&foo;

bar[0] = ...;
bar[1] = ...;
```

If you typically access your data via bitfield and only rarely access it by DWORD, then this might be an acceptable solution.

Comment: Note that the standard does not offer any guarantee on the layout of bitfields (well, not many at least). In particular, it is platform dependent whether the first field of a bitfield will use the lower or highest bits of the underlying type.

Comment: Even more specifically than platform dependent, it's implementation defined. Two compilers targeting the same platform could use different bitfield allocation layouts.

Comment: David, Michael- Good points, I meant to include that in my original post.  Bitfields leave so much up to the implementation that they're extremely difficult to use portably.  The only truly portable way to do this is to specify each bit and byte explicitly (that is, treat the structure as a byte array, access bytes using indices, and access bits using bitmasks).